# Program crashes after it compiles

Tags: c++, loops, crash

I am writing a program for my C++ class and can't seem to figure out what the problem with is with my code.  The code compiles but something causes the program to crash after line 16 that I just can't figure out.

```
#include <iostream>

// Declare Global variables and Prototyping
int const TAX = .07;
float inputStickerPrice();

int main()
{
    float totalStickerPrice = 0.0, discount = 0.0, totalPrice = 0.0;
    char* pass = "";

// Calculate the total sticker price
    while (pass != "n")
    {
        totalStickerPrice +=  inputStickerPrice();
        std::cout << "Would you like to enter another item? [y/n] ";
        std::cin >> pass;

// Pass validation Loop
        while (pass != "y" && pass != "n")
        {
            std::cout << "INVALID INPUT. Please enter y for yes or n for no. ";
            std::cin >> pass;
        } // End of Pass Loop

    } // End of Sticker Price Loop

//  Input Discount
    while (!(discount >= 0.0 && discount <= 1))
    {
        std::cout << "Please enter the discount: ";
        std::cin >> discount;

// Validate input
        if (!(discount >= 0.0 && discount <= 1))
        {
            std::cout << "INVALID INPUT. Discount must be between 0.0 and 1.0. ";
        } // End of validation

    } // End of Discount Loop

    totalPrice = totalStickerPrice * discount; // Apply Discount to total Sticker Price
    std::cout << "The Subtotal is: " << totalPrice << std::endl;
    totalPrice *= (1+TAX); // Apply Tax to Subtotal
    std::cout << "The Cost after Tax is: " << totalPrice << std::endl;

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}

//**********************
//  Input sub program  *
//**********************

float inputStickerPrice()
{
    using namespace std;
    float sticker = 0.0;

    cout << "Please input the sticker price of the item: ";
    cin >> sticker;

// Validation Loop
    while(!(sticker >= 0.0 && sticker <= 9999.99))
    {
    cout << "INVALID INPUT. Please input a value between 0 and 9999.99: ";
    cin >> sticker;
    } // End of Validation Loop

    return sticker;

} // End of Input Function
```

Comment: You're trying to read into a string litteral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char* pass = "";
```

Here you declared a pointer to a string literal, an array of characters which occupies a region of storage that you're not allowed to modify. Recent compilers that follow C++11 standard are supposed to produce an error for this line, because string literals are not implicitly convertible to `char*` anymore, but to `const char*` instead.

When you modify this memory in this line `std::cin >> pass;` your program has undefined behaviour and all bets are off. A crash is just one of possible outcomes.

Next, you can't compare strings like that:

```
pass != "y"
```

`pass` is a pointer and `"y"` decays to one. You're not comparing contents of string here, but pointer values that will never be the same.

Forget about pointers until you're ready to tackle them, use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class instead. Then comparing strings will be as easy as `str1 == str2`.

Answer (score 1):

```
while (pass != "n")
```

`pass` is a pointer, so you should use `*pass` or `pass[0]` if you want to obain its value.

Besides look at @Borgleader comment

EDIT:

Change `char pass*;` into `std::string pass;` - it should fix the issue.

Comment: That would not cause the program to crash. In fact this will always be true because he's comparing the adress of 2 different string litterals.

Comment: Right, I was too fast to think about it. I'll fix that.